# Convert a variable in multiple dataframes to character in R

Tags: r

I have 4 datasets:(y25_age,y30_age,y25_mri,y30_mri). Each dataset has an ID variable. I want to convert the ID format from numeric to character in the above datasets. I have tried the below code

```
x<-list(y25_age,y30_age,y25_mri,y30_mri)

x$ID<-lapply(x,function(x){x<-x["ID"]<-as.character(x["ID"])})
```

However, this gives an output of all the IDs as characters, which is not what I want. Any suggestions are welcome? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the lhs to `<-` should be `x` and there should be a return statement for 'x'

```
x <- lapply(x,function(u){u$ID <-as.character(u$ID)
       u})
```

NOTE: changed the anonymous function from 'x' to 'u' to avoid any confusion

Or another option is `transform`

```
x <- lapply(x, transform, ID = as.character(ID))
```

If the intention is to change the original objects, the 'x' should be a named `list`

```
names(x) <- c('y25_age','y30_age','y25_mri','y30_mri')
```

and then use `list2env`

```
list2env(x, .GlobalEnv) # not recommended though
```

Answer (score 1):

this should also work

```
library(tidyverse)
map(x, ~ .x %>% mutate(ID = as.character(ID)))
```